# Replace sql query to core data fetch request

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

how to replace an sql query into Core Data fetch request?
This is the query:

```
NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM diario GROUP BY strftime('%%d', date_time) ORDER BY date_time"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `NSPredicate` class along with a `NSSortDescriptor` to sort the results. That would be something like:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"diario" inManagedObjectContext:moc];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:/*Your predicate here*/];
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date_time" ascending:YES];

fetchRequest.entity = entity;
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate;
fetchRequest.sortDescriptor = sort;
```

Comment: Yes, but I would group by days dates, I have got more dates and I would grouping by day. Sorry for my english...